# Setting the mouse speed high is problematic with multiple windows on multiple displays

Tags: multiple-monitors, mouse, touchpad, mouse-pointer, usability

- Does the community think the problem described below is worth considering?
- What suggestions do you have for making the mouse easier to track?
- If there's not some setting that is a good solution, where can I find individuals with similar ideas who might be willing to work with me on getting these ideas implemented?

Problem:  While moving the mouse, if the mouse speed is too high, it is easy to lose track of where the mouse is going, especially between two monitors. The problem is challenging when there are multiple windows where text entry is possible, and the mouse cursor is switching between a fairly visible arrow and a thin vertical line when moving across a text window.

It can be difficult to find where the mouse landed if the end of the mouse movement is inside a text window with lots of text because the thin cursor is buried in a mass of text. Although it's blinking, That's insufficient to find it quickly if your eyes are trying to track its movement.  The feeling is, "Where did it go?"

### Here's my ideas on this:

- First idea:

I want the cursor to remain an arrow while moving between windows and changing in some way when it "lands" in a window, with a slight delay before switching to the landing window's cursor.

There is a setting that allows the left ctrl key to "locate" the cursor, which might get annoying when using the ctrl key for its intended purpose. It's annoying to even have to use it because you've "lost track of the cursor" with all that fast movement and which monitor is it on?

- Second Idea:

Haptic feedback in the mouse.  The mouse has a haptic element that produces a "thump" when you cross either a window boundary or move from one monitor to another.

- Third Idea:

Sound feedback when you move across a window boundary, and a slightly different sound when you move from window to window.